# Multi-service architecture and multiple databases

Tags: spring, architecture

For the popular music streaming service architecture developed with Spring, is it right to have all models in one module and one database with strong RDMB like PostgreSQL? Or have a separate database for each service?
Exactly my question is which model is optimal?

Comment: A big problem in separate databases is reporting. The second problem is the high cost of exchanging messages between microservices with queue management tools such as Kafka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is about good code design or good application design, I think multiple databases don't bring many benefits but high cost. If you want a well maintainable application think about multiple namespaces inside your data model. Which parts of your model are high cohesive? Which parts should be loosely coupled? Split loosely coupled parts into different namespaces. If you want to have loosely coupled services avoid to glue them together on the database layer by joining data. In my opinion the "diamond architecture" is an antipattern. I think "Domain-Driven Design" is a good practice for designing Well structured data models. But the different namespaces of course can be stored in a single database instance.

If your question is about "good architecture", think about your quality requirements. What do you mean with "multi-service architecture"? What are your goals? Do you want to be able to deploy your services independently, it's very important to avoid heigh coupling due to a bad data model. But it's not necessary to split the model over multiple databases. If your goal is to have hight available services, so that even if one of your services has crashed, the others are still available, you should definitely think about multiple databases. If multiple services are based on a single database instance you get a single point of failure.